# Accessing the C Interface from the C/C++ BLPAPI SDK

Tags: c, bloomberg, blpapi

I'm trying to use the Bloomberg API with C instead of C++. However, there doesn't seem to be any documentation online regarding this usage, aside from a sentence in the Developer's Guide on pg.78:

"... while the C interface provides a C-style version
of the object model."

I can't find any evidence of a C Interface in the C/C++ SDK download. There are some DLLs in the /lib folder though; are these DLL files the C Interface?

Comment: The [header files](http://bloomberg.github.io/blpapi-docs/cpp/3.9/files.html) declare a bunch of functions with C linkage alongside the various classes.  They appear to be intended for use from both C and C++, so I would expect that both languages would be supported by the same DLLs, or at least that those supporting C are a subset of those supporting C++.  By all appearances, however, Bloomberg's claim to support C is a bit vacuous, at the very least in the sense that support requires documentation, which does indeed seem to be lacking.